# gdal_translate not using correct types when resampling

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm using gdal_translate to downsample some data using averaging. The input data uses an Int data type, and I want to store the float values of the pixel averaging.

However, even when I force gdal_translate to use Float32, the values in the output file have been cast to int. The command I'm using is:

```
gdal_translate -tr 0.0075 0.0075 -r average -ot Float32 -co COMPRESS=LZW -q in.tif out.tif
```

When I use the same options for gdalwarp, I get the expected result (float values).

```
gdalwarp -tr 0.0075 0.0075 -r average -ot Float32 -co COMPRESS=LZW -q in.tif out.tif
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in gdal_translate?

Comment: I believe the same thing applies with gdal_calc.py, where you need to convert image to float explicitly (in expression, e.g. --calc="A.astype(float)"). Since it calculates expression first and only after that converts resulting image into -ot type

Comment: The order of the options does not make a difference (nor should it!)

@dr_times Yes, I've encountered that with gdal_calc.py; I wondered if it might be a similar issue. However there's no similar ability to force casting for gdal_translate.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is a bit hard to understand, but this is an expected result given the design of both utilities. In gdal_translate, the resampling is done with the input datatype (so Int), the conversion to the output data type is done late in the process. In gdalwarp, -ot Float32 implies a -wt Float32 (working datatype), hence more expected results.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the -wt option for gdalwarp. AFAICT there's no equivalent option for gdal_translate - correct?